# Poner por defecto el valor seleccionar con una funcion javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo poner por defecto el valor seleccionar con una funcion javascript

```
<select id='tipoDocumento' 
  name='tipoDocumento' class='select2-container select2me form-control'>
<option value=''>Seleccionar</option>
<?php
foreach ($tipoDocumento as $i=>$descripcion){
  if ($_POST['tipoDocumento']==$i){
    echo "<option value ='" . $i ."'selected>". $descripcion ."</option>";
  }else{
    echo "<option value ='" . $i ."'>". $descripcion ."</option>";
  }
}
?>
</select>
```

El `select` lo relleno con datos de una base que tengo, pero no logro poner con un botón que en el `onclick` llame a una función, el valor de Seleccionar como cuando recién se carga la pagina.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te refieres a resetear al valor original despues que lo cambias?

Comment: Sí, es lo que necesito. Volver al valor original una vez que ya fue seleccionado algún valor, lo quiero hacer con un boton

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que guardar el valor original en una variable y resetearlo cuando el boton es presionado.  Algo asi:

```js
var valor = document.getElementById("tipoDocumento").value;

function resetear() {
  document.getElementById("tipoDocumento").value = valor;
}
```

```html
<select id='tipoDocumento' name='tipoDocumento' class='select2-container select2me form-control'>
  <option value=''>Seleccionar</option>
  <option value='1'>carta</option>
  <option value='2' selected>foto</option>
</select>

<button id="reset" onClick="resetear();">Resetear</button>
```

Comment: Lo voy a probar, a ver que tal, muchas gracias por responder tan rápido!

Comment: De nada y bienvenido a StackOverfow en Español.

Comment: Muchas gracias alan, intenté con la idea que me diste, pero la verdad no cambia el valor, sigue quedando el valor que se elegio en el select, no tienes alguna otra idea de como resolverlo? te agradezco!

Comment: Ya viste que aqui si funciona, otra forma de acerlo seria un input hidden y guardar el valor ahi.

Comment: es lo que no entiendo, lo intenté tal cual está en el ejemplo que me diste, pero no logro que funcione

Comment: Intenta poner el script despues de declarar el select.

Comment: ya lo intenté, y nada :(

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar esto `

```html
<body onload="funcion()">
```

`
se ejecuta la función cada que recargas la pagina sin poner un botón!

Comment: es un muy buen dato, para tener en cuenta. Pero la idea es resetear el select con un boton en pantalla sin hacer un reload de la página

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es guardar el id del elemento seleccionado al cargar la página:

```
foreach ($tipoDocumento as $i=>$descripcion){
  if ($_POST['tipoDocumento']==$i){
    echo "<option value ='" . $i ."'selected>". $descripcion ."</option>";
    $seleccionado = $i;
  }else{
    echo "<option value ='" . $i ."'>". $descripcion ."</option>";
  }
}
```

Luego en un en javascript puedes crear una función para cargar el valor inicial al select:

```
<script>
  function cambiarSeleccionado () {
    var seleccionado = <?php echo $seleccionado ?>;
    document.getElementById('tipoDocumento').value = seleccionado;
  }
</script>
```

Esta función la puedes mandar llamar desde un botón en el onclick. Te dejo el link del php de ejemplo. [Ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w-Zrk5A7KQ0nt6c6AaXX5bR-Mum9M-sV)

Comment: tiene lógica, pero no me ejecuta la funcion javascript

Comment: el javascript tienes que agregarlo en el mismo archivo .php, de lo contrario no va a funcionar

Comment: muchas gracias por responder Eduardo, sí lo hice en el mismo archivo php, pero no me ejecuta la función, se puede igualar una variable como lo haces dentro de las etiquetas de php?

Comment: si se puede, acabo de hacer un pequeño script en php y si funciona, puse algunos datos de prueba, voy a editar la respuesta para poner el link del archivo. php y que lo puedas descargar.